# ajax success returns <?php<?php<?php<?php as first line

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am sending HTML code to ajax, and appending this code to the bottom of a list.  Its for ajax paginating.

The code returned starts with

```
<?php<?php<?php<?php
```

and ends with

```
[1]
```

what I am send is an array of html formatted activity items.  This is an example of what I am getting back in ajax.

```
<?php<?php<?php<?php
<div class="activity">
<div class="activity-top"></div>
<div class="activity-body"></div>
</div>[1]
```

the item I am sending IS in an array.

the function returning code to looks like

```
function run_loop() {
    $each_item = array();
        if( has_activities( array('current_page' => $_POST['this_page'], 'user_id' => $_POST['user_id'] ) ) ) {

        while ( activity() ) : the_activity();

        $each_item[] =  include( dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/activity/activity-entry.php' );

        endwhile;
    }
    exit(json_encode($each_item));

}
```

Additionally, I tried working with the html code despite it being broken, and the parent div (container for activity) returned is not displayed.  I am using `.append()`.

Comment: Whats in /activity/activity-entry.php???

Comment: show your activity-entry.php file code

Comment: activity-entry.php is just a template for the loop. It contains the divs i pasted above, along with some php functions that populate those divs.

Comment: @GregL : That might be the actual problem.. It'l be good if u can post that code also..

Comment: no it literally just has a function that echoes the username, and another that echoes an avatar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you have two potential problems:

1. You are rendering your activity-entry.php file as plain text.
2. You are the Ajax method is returning a PHP array that is being written as its string representation by append.

A better way to handle this would be to return only the data you need, preferably in a format easily parsed by JavaScript (JSON), and then to render that data to HTML using jQuery, i.e.
$('#pager').append('' + data +''

Comment: So just clone an existing div and replace the content within it?  How would I handle it if someone does not have an existing activity item though? There would be nothing to clone.   I like your idea though

Comment: Well, you might have a template defined in JavaScript as a string, var template = '<div class ="item">ITEM</item>', replace ITEM with your content, and then append the result.